# ref.current.focus() is null

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

I have a icon and a input field. While onclick on icon i need to focus on the input.

Code:

```
const inputRef = useRef(null)
```

Icon:

```
<ChatIcon className="btn" onClick={inputRef.current.focus()} />
```

Input:

```
  <input
    placeholder="add a comment..."
    type="text"
    value={comment}
    ref={inputRef}
    onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
  />
```

Error:

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus')**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function before its click you need to add it like this

```js
<ChatIcon className="btn" onClick={inputRef.current.focus} />
```

or if you wanna be safer

```js
<ChatIcon className="btn" onClick={() => inputRef.current && inputRef.current.focus()} />
```

Comment: I think you didn't need to right too much code you can simple add 
<ChatIcon className="btn" onClick={() => inputRef.current?.focus()} />

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` calls the return value of the argument you passed in. That's what it is